# cURL + PHP - Anexos nos cards do Trello

Tags: php, libcurl, trello

Fala pessoal, tudo bem?

Alguém já usou requisições cURL do PHP para fazer o envio de um anexo para a API do trello pode me explicar melhor como funciona?

Tenho uma página em HTML com alguns input type="text", alguns select e um input type="file" multiple.

Para enviar os dados, estou usando fazendo da seguinte forma:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var files = document.getElementById('anexoTrello').files;

var formData = new FormData();

for(i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++){
  formData.append('file[]', myFiles[i]);
}
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open('POST', 'assets/php/ajaxResponse.php');
ajax.send(formData);
```

**PHP ajaxResponse**

```
if(!empty($_FILES)){
  for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) { 
    $chAttachment = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($chAttachment, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.trello.com/1/cards/tQxhxRJO/attachments?key=key&token=token');

    curl_setopt($chAttachment, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(
      array(
        'name' => $_FILES['file']['name'][$i],
        'file' => $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]
      )
    ));

    curl_setopt($chAttachment, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($chAttachment);
    curl_close($chAttachment);
    print_r($result);
  }
}
```

Onde o key e token são de uso pessoal.

Acontece que, os anexos são criados no cartão de id **tQxhxRJO**, porém, no trello eles mostram o nome do arquivo pois determinei pelo curl_setopt através do name o nome que quero, mas todos os arquivos enviados vão com 14 bytes, ou seja, ele não faz o upload corretamente, quando clico para fazer o download ou abrir os anexos no cartão do trello, o download é realizado com um arquivo de nome Upload, se você abre o arquivo com algum editor de textos, vai ver que contém o nome do arquivo enviado.

Alguém sabe como fazer o upload via cURL corretamente?

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

É porque você de fato está enviando o conteúdo do arquivo apenas o nome dele.

```
'file' => $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]
```

Aqui nessa parte você está configurando o conteúdo do arquivo como o path dele.

O correto seria ler o arquivo e enviar o conteúdo do arquivo, e não apenas o caminho.

```
'file' => file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i])
```

Comment: Obrigado! Eu tentei dessa forma, ele até funciona! porém quando ele é enviado, ao invés de mostrar o nome do arquivo, continua como Upload e quando faço o download pelo Trello e altero a extensão para a correta, png por exemplo, ele retorna que o formato não é válido, o que me parece é que quando eu envio pro servidor do trello via API esse arquivo ao invés de ir com o conteúdo do arquivo ele modifica adicionando vários % e aumenta o tamanho do arquivo, tem alguma idéia do que pode ser?

Comment: Realmente não sei dizer, mas aconselho a dar um sleep no for para dar uma folga. E tentar com apenas um arquivo, ao invés de múltiplos.

Comment: Consegui resolver! @jardson-sales

Criei uma array chamada args, e dentro dela eu fiz o seguinte:

$args = array(
  'file' => new CurlFile($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['type'],$_FILES['file']['name']),
  'key'   => 'minhakey',
  'token' => 'meutoken',
  'mimeType' => $_FILES['file']['type'],
  'name' => $_FILES['file']['name']
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'cartao no trello');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

Answer (score -2):

Resolvido! vou deixar o código aqui caso alguém precise de ajuda nisso, obrigado Jardson por dar uma boa parte da solução!

```
$args = array(
  'file' => new CurlFile($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['type'],$_FILES['file']['name']),
  'key'   => 'minhakey',
  'token' => 'meutoken',
  'mimeType' => $_FILES['file']['type'],
  'name' => $_FILES['file']['name']
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.trello.com/1/cards/tkuiZzpA/attachments/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```